# make: text-function in a dependancy

Tags: makefile

Learning make, In the following Makefile, how can I define the dependancy of `%.tar.bz2` to be `somefile.tar.bz2`?

It would be something like:
`%.tar.bz2: $(function_to_cut_from_end_till_/ %.tar.bz2)`
But I couldn't find how to do it in `man make`.

Am I approaching this from the wrong side?

```
source=http://example.net/somefile.tar.bz2
source:=$(subst :,\:,$(source))

.PHONY: download

download: $(source)

%.tar.bz2:
        @wget "$@"
```

Comment: "function_to_cut_from_end_till_/" exists and is called "notdir", but: 1. Any functions you use in the prerequisites of a pattern rule are only evaluated once, *before* the `%` placeholder is replaced by anything else, and 2. even ignoring that, I don't see how `%.tar.bz2: $(function_to_cut_from_end_till_/ %.tar.bz2)` is a useful thing to do. Could you explain the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: just wanted to use make, instead of shell for getting file name - you are right, putting it as a dependancy won't make any sense. I will use `notdir` inside of a rule.
would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the filename part of the target name inside the commands of the `%.tar.bz2` rule, you could use [the notdir function](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/File-Name-Functions.html), or [the $(@D) variable](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Automatic-Variables.html#index-g_t_0024_0028_0040_0040D_0029-959).

Really, though, you should make the target name match the output file, so that `make` can check for existence of the file, and won't try to download it anew each time you run it. A simple way to do that would be

```
source=somefile.tar.bz2

.PHONY: download

download: $(source)

%.tar.bz2:
        @wget "http://example.net/$@"
```

or, if you have different source archives to download from different locations (which I imagine you do, otherwise why bother with a template rule at all?), you could use a [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Target_002dspecific.html) to store the download URL, like this

```
source=somefile.tar.bz2 some-other-file.tar.bz2
somefile.tar.bz2: URL=http://example.net
some-other-file.tar.bz2: URL=http://example.org/foobar

.PHONY: download

download: $(source)

%.tar.bz2:
        @wget "$(URL)/$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, no reason to be too complicated - while it might be possible to do that, wouldn't it be much more readable to do this:

```
domain=http://example.net/
filename=somefile.tar.bz2
source=$(DOMAIN)$(FILENAME)
```

Then the filename is right there to use

You could also try

```
$(patsubst %/,,$(source))
```

Which should remove everything up to the last forward slash from `$(source)`